# URL Rewrite - additional symbols in second group "/?"

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm trying to evaluate URL Rewrite pattern, but for second value it's giving me to much:

My URL:

```
news/group/?page=2
```

My pattern:

```
group/([^\.]+)/?page=([0-9]+)
```

Group value:

```
{R:0} news/group/?page=2
{R:1} group/?
{R:2} 2
```

How to modify my pattern to have in {R:1} just "group" value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anwser was simply, as I wanted to have query_string as is.

I changed pattern to:

```
^group/([^\.]+)/$
```

And under action set:

```
 <action ...  appendQueryString="true" />
```

Which was just adding that ?page=2 query string to rewritten url.